# Adding JavaScript code with jQuery.html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 

           var x="<script>alert('hello world');</script>";

           $("#div_one").html(x);

    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="div_one">
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why does this not work? I'd expect the JS code between the script tags to be interpreted and see an alert message ...

What I want to do:

I have written a set of functions that add and delete items from an array depending on the user input (JavaScript). Then, I have a function that draws() a ul-list of the items held in the array. Behind each item, I want to provide a remove link, which calls a JavaScript function that removes the item from the array and then calls drawList() to redraw the list.

If there weren't that security policy, I'd simply do it as in the code shown above.

Comment: Browsers have security in place to stop scripts being injected into your page. If you need to run some JS code, attach it to an event.

Comment: ^^^^ What he said, and try `var x="<scr"+"ipt>alert('hello world');</scr"+"ipt>";` to hack around the issue

Comment: Usually, adding code like this uses `document.write` instead of `.html()` (`.innerHTML()`). Either way, it would be easier to help you with a more practical example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - It doesn't make sense because if someone can inject scripts using JavaScript, then he already has access to the document's script.

Comment: I dynamically create a list of links of the format <a href=# onClick=jsFunc( danymically_created_parameter)>link</a> ... jsFunc(), however, never fires, due to the browser's security police I assume. Any work-around for this? Thanks

Comment: But your using jQuery, why don't you create the elements properly with the event handlers added during creation ?

Comment: Well before rushing into figuring out why this isn't working why don't we ask the question "what" are you trying to do. That way we can recommend to proper way to solve your problem. That way its not only helpful for you but other people who might also be walking down this road.

Comment: I have added an explanation of what I want to do..

Comment: You'd delete an item by alerting "Hello World", how exactly would that work ?

Comment: That's just an example I gave since I wanted to know if it was possible to insert <script> generally..

Answer (score 1):

That is some weird browser bug I believe. For some reason you can't have `</script>` inside the script block.

Change to

```
var x="<scr"+"ipt>alert('hello world');</scr"+"ipt>";
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2tyZ/)

Comment: What is the bug, that it doesn't get interpreted or your 'hack'?

Comment: I wouldn't call it weird, it is in the HTML parsing spec. The first `</script>` token encountered after `<script>` will close the given script element.

Comment: @usario the fact that the parser ignores that `</script>` is inside a string `""` and parses as if was the closing tag.

Comment: @BrunoLM The parser will not ignore `</script>` even if it is inside quotes.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I think you misread or misinterpreted what I said. I said exactly what you said in other words.

Comment: @BrunoLM - Oops! The way you put it together is kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a bug. The problem is here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

       var x="<script>alert('hello world');</script>";

       $("#div_one").html(x);

});
</script>
```

The browser thinks the first `<script>` tag is associated with the `</script>` inside your code.

[image]

As you can see, the code is shown in the DOM instead of executing.

To further prove it, see this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Ah8Qz/

```
var x = $("<script>").html("alert('hello world');");
$("#div_one").append(x);
```

If you avoid the `</script>` closing tag, then there will be no problem because the HTML parser will ignore any open `<script>` tag inside `<script>`.

---

So to sum up,

- Browsers does not have security in place to stop scripts being injected into your page.
- This is no where near a browser bug.